# Please can I get help with using T-SQL to loop through all user databases in a SQL server instance

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Please can anyone help me with how to loop through all the User databases in an instance executing the below query for each one of them?

The script returns a list of users with their individual permissions in a separate statement.

```
SELECT 'USE '+ DB_NAME()+'; '+CASE WHEN dp.state <> 'W' THEN dp.state_desc ELSE 'GRANT' END +' ' + 
        dp.permission_name + ' TO ' + QUOTENAME(dpg.name) COLLATE database_default + 
        CASE WHEN dp.state <> 'W' THEN '' ELSE ' WITH GRANT OPTION' END +';' AS [-- Permission To Be Assign to the User --]
FROM    sys.database_permissions AS dp
INNER JOIN sys.database_principals AS dpg ON dp.grantee_principal_id = dpg.principal_id
WHERE   dp.major_id = 0 AND dpg.principal_id > 4
        AND (dpg.type in ('S','G','U'))
        AND dpg.name NOT LIKE '##%##'
        AND dpg.name NOT LIKE 'NT AUTHORITY%'
        AND dpg.name NOT LIKE 'NT SERVICE%'
        AND dpg.name <> ('sa')
        AND dpg.default_schema_name IS NOT NULL
        AND dpg.name <> 'distributor_admin'
        AND dpg.principal_id > 4
ORDER BY dpg.name
```

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at Aaron Bertrand's excellent [sp_foreachdb](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/)  - and he also has a very useful partner  [sp_ineachdb](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5686/execute-a-command-in-the-context-of-each-database-in-sql-server-using-spineachdb/) which may be more what you're looking for here.

Comment: thank you so much. You are correct, sp_ineachdb looks like what I need, much appreciated.